# append the same element to several sublists in python

Tags: python, list, append, nested-lists

I have a list of lists like this:

```
L=[[[1,2,3],[4,5]],[[6,7,8,9],[10]]]
```

I want to append the integer 11 to the subsublists 1 and 3. I can do something like:

```
L[0][2].append(11)
L[1][2].append(11)
```

Is there a simpler way to do it in Python ?

Because in my case, let's say I have a list with 100 sublists, and these sublists have 100 sublists (comparable to a (100,100)-matrix) and I want to append a value to the sublists from nb 50 to 75 of the sublists from nb 10 to 20.

So right now I do something like:

```
for i in range(10,21):
    for j in range(50,76):
        L[i][j].append(value)
```

Is there a more efficient way ? Like with numpy arrays we can do

```
L=[10..21,50..76]=value
```

Comment: Numpy arrays will be way more efficient!

Comment: Your for-loop is already the best you can do with Python's builtins. Don't know how Numpy performs compared to that though...

Comment: I didnt figure out how to use numpy arrays in this case since `L[i][j].size` changes with i and j. Is it possible to use arrays in this case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to use numpy arrays in this case since L[i][j].size changes with i and j. Is it possible to use arrays in this case ?

Yes, but the `dtype` is `object` in such case.

```
L=[[[1,2,3],[4,5]],[[6,7,8,9],[10]]]
L=np.array(L) # L is a ndarray of list
# array([[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]], [[6, 7, 8, 9], [10]]], dtype=object)
value=100
for i in L[0:1,0:2].flatten():
  i.append(value)
# array([[[1, 2, 3, 100], [4, 5, 100]], [[6, 7, 8, 9], [10]]], dtype=object)
```

In this example, `L` is a `numpy.ndarray` of python `list` objects.

```
type(L)
# <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
type(L[0,0])
# <type 'list'>
```

#### Arithmetic operation on jagged array

It is possible to perform efficient arithmetic operation on the jagged array like `L` using numpy.

```
marr = np.vectorize(np.array,otypes=[np.ndarray])
L=[[[1,2,3],[4,5]],[[6,7,8,9],[10]]]
L=marr(L) # L is a ndarray of ndarray
L+L
# array([[array([2, 4, 6]), array([ 8, 10])],[array([12, 14, 16, 18]), array([20])]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Can the dtype be "ndarray" ? So once I filled up the array I can use the mathematical properties of ndarrays to, for example, do something like L+L ?

Comment: Yes, you can do arithmetic operation on `L`, but the result may be surprising `L+L => array([[[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 4, 5]],[[6, 7, 8, 9, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 10]]], dtype=object)`

Comment: Thank you for your response, exactly what I was looking for. However you say "perform efficient arithmetic operation" whereas I read in the "vectorize" documentation that it is not more efficient than a for loop

Comment: On principle you should have some performance bonus because every element of `marr` is a numpy array. So you just need a 2 dimensional loop rather than a 3D loop (if you store every number in nested lists). Also it always saves you lots of memory allocation time to avoid using python list.