# python jagged array operation efficiency

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, jagged-arrays

I am new to Python and I am looking for the most efficient way to do operations with a jagged array.

I have a jagged array like this:

```
A = array([[array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5])],[array([6, 7, 8, 9]), array([10])]], dtype=object)
```

I want to be able to do things like this:

```
A=A[A>4]
B=A+A
```

Apparently python is very efficient for doing operations like this with numpy arrays, but unfortunetely I need to do this for jagged arrays and I havent found such an object in Python. Does it exist in Python, or is there a library that allows to do efficient operations with jagged arrays ?

For the example I gave, here are the outputs I'd like:

```
A = array([[array([]), array([5])],[array([6, 7, 8, 9]), array([10])]], dtype=object)
B = array([[array([]), array([10])],[array([12, 14, 16, 18]), array([20])]], dtype=object)
```

But maybe the way Python works it simply cannot do efficient operations with jagged arrays like it does with numpy arrays, I dont know the details.

Comment: This is quite a fundamental limitation of numpy - in order to perform vectorized operations on arrays they need to contain scalars of the same type, and be regularly strided in each dimension. Perhaps you could use a `scipy.sparse` array where the column dimension is the same as the longest 'row' in the jagged array?

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this solution and see how it performs

Comment: The only case where an array of jagged arrays is better is if it needs to be 2d (or larger).  Reshaping such an array is much easier than playing with the nesting of an equivalent list of lists.  But a 1d array of arrays is seldom, if ever, better than a flat list of arrays.

Comment: The `lil_matrix` sparse format stores its values as 2 object arrays of lists - a list for each row.  The only thing sparse matrices do more efficiently, other than storage, is matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

Your array is 2x2:

```
In [298]: A
Out[298]: 
array([[array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5])],
       [array([6, 7, 8, 9]), array([10])]], dtype=object)
```

While `A+A` works, boolean tests have not been implemented for this kind of array:

```
In [299]: A>4
...
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I'm going to flatten `A` because it makes it easier to compare with list operations:

```
In [301]: A1=A.flatten()

In [303]: A1+A1
Out[303]: 
array([array([2, 4, 6]), array([ 8, 10]), array([12, 14, 16, 18]),
       array([20])], dtype=object)

In [304]: [a+a for a in A1]
Out[304]: [array([2, 4, 6]), array([ 8, 10]), array([12, 14, 16, 18]), array([20])]

In [305]: timeit A1+A1
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.85 µs per loop

In [306]: timeit [a+a for a in A1]
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.09 µs per loop
```

The array operation is a bit faster than a list comprehension.  But if I first turn the array into a list:

```
In [307]: A1l=A1.tolist()

In [308]: A1l
Out[308]: [array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5]), array([6, 7, 8, 9]), array([10])]

In [309]: timeit [a+a for a in A1l]
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.2 µs per loop
```

times improve.  This is a good indication that the `A1+A1` (or even `A+A`) is using a similar sort of iteration.

So the straight forward way of performing your `A,B` calculation is

```
In [310]: A2=[a[a>4] for a in A1]
In [311]: B=[a+a for a in A2]
In [312]: B
Out[312]: [array([], dtype=int32), array([10]), array([12, 14, 16, 18]), array([20])]
```

(we can convert to/from arrays and lists as needed).

A `numpy` array stores its data a flat databuffer, and uses the `shape` and `strides` attributes to quickly calculate the location of any element, regardless of the dimensions.  The fast array operations use compiled code that rapidly steps though the databuffers of arguments, performing the operations element by element (or some other combination).

A `dtype` `object` array also has the flat databuffer, but the elements are pointers to lists or arrays elsewhere.  So while it can index individual elements quickly, it still has to perform a Python call(s) to access the arrays.  So especially when the array is 1d, it is virtually the same as a flat list with the same pointers.

Multidimensional object arrays are nicer than nested lists.  You can reshape them, access elements (`A[1,3]` v `Al[1][3]`), transpose them, etc.  But when it comes to iterating through all the subarrays they don't offer much of a benefit.

Looking again at your 2d array:

```
In [315]: timeit A+A
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.93 µs per loop  # 6.85 for A1+A1 (above)

In [316]: timeit [[j+j for j in i] for i in A]
100000 loops, best of 3: 17.1 µs per loop

In [317]: Al = A.tolist()

In [318]: timeit [[j+j for j in i] for i in Al]
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.01 µs per loop    # 5.2 for A1l flat list
```

Basically the same time for summing the array and iterating through the equivalent nested list.

Answer (score 0):

The performance of numpy jagged array may not be optimal, but there are enough reasons to believe that it should be much better than using python nested list. As explained in your [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36981925/append-the-same-element-to-several-sublists-in-python):

> On principle you should have some performance bonus because every element is a numpy array. So you just need a 2 dimensional loop rather than a 3D loop (if you store every number in nested lists). Also it always saves you lots of memory allocation time to avoid using python list.

Here is a simple test:

```
import time,sys,random
import numpy as np
rand = np.random.rand
L = np.array([[rand(100), rand(200)],[rand(400), rand(300)]], dtype=object)
L1 = [random.random() for i in range(1000)]
arrFunc = np.vectorize(lambda x:x[x>0.3],otypes=[np.ndarray])

start = time.time()
if sys.argv[1]=='np':
  for i in range(100000):
    B=i*L
else:
  for i in range(100000):
    B=[i*x for x in L1]

end = time.time()
print ('Arithmetic Op: ', end-start)


start = time.time()
if sys.argv[1]=='np':
  for i in range(100000):
    B=arrFunc(L)
else:
  for i in range(100000):
    B=[x for x in L1 if x<0.3]
end = time.time()
print ('Indexing       ', end-start)
```

Result:

```
> python testNpJarray.py np
Arithmetic Op:  3.9719998836517334
Indexing        8.079999923706055

> python testNpJarray.py list
Arithmetic Op:  53.289000034332275
Indexing        52.10899996757507
```

This test may not be quite fare because the outter numpy array is quite small, you are welcome to change the size to fit into your application and tell us the results.

Comment: I have no doubt it is more efficient with math operations (and it is way clearer), but how to do things like "A=A[A>4]" with a jagged array in an efficient way ?

Comment: Some operations work across this `object` dtype boundary, but not all.  While `L*3` and `L+10` works, `L>10` does not. Indexing does not cross this boundary, you can't select the 1st element of each subarray without a list comprehension.  Or even get the shape of each subarray.

Comment: Your `L` is 2d.  I get better times with `[i*x for x in L.flatten()]` where each `x` is a 'pure' array, not another object array.

Comment: The answer has been updated to show how to do "B=A[A>0.3]" in an efficient way. It uses `np.vectorize` which only loops over the outer array (of size 2x2). This method applies to all operations that cannot work across the `object` dtype boundary.